How to remove @babel/plugin-transform-classes from build?
I upgraded to next.js 15 and in lighthouse started getting warning: Avoid serving legacy JavaScript to modern browsers
The culprit seems to be @babel/plugin-transform-classes
How can I exclude @babel/plugin-transform-classes from my build in next.js 15?
I have looked through the documentation and don't see anything that says how to explicitly remove this from my build. I don't have a .babelrc / babel.config.js file or any related babel entries in my package.json
I need to find some way to disable it without using .babelrc because I am using next/font and next fonts requires SWC. Adding a .babelrc disables SWC.
I have also adjusted my browserslist to:
"browserslist":
[
"defaults",
">0.2%",
"not ie <= 11",
"not op_mini all"
]
I still get the warning in lighthouse
